# In React material tree table when i add a new row in tree table that row should be expand default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

<MaterialTable title="title" columns={columns} data={data} icons={tableIcons} parentChildData={(row, rows) => rows.find((a) => a.id === row.productId)} />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<MaterialTable title="title" columns={columns} data={data} icons={tableIcons} parentChildData={(row, rows) => rows.find((a) => a.id === row.productId)} defaultExpanded/>
```